# Swift XCTest Cell Loaded in Test, but all outlets are nil, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xctest

I have created a sample project for this question, found [here](https://drive.google.com/a/gymbudapp.com/file/d/0B82x-HRXwjSqVjlYSnBsN1JoalE/view?usp=sharing)

What I have is a `ViewController`, which is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, and I am loading into it custom cells, named `TableViewCell`. The regular build works great, and if you run it 3 cells should appear, each with a label `"Cell i"` where i is that cell's row.

The problem arises when I try and create a test for this cell. In the project above I have a test class `TableVewTestTestTests.swift` (the name is ridiculous, my fault) that mocks a `ViewController tableView` and proceeds to fetch a cell properly, but then when attempting to verify the cell's outlets, they are all `nil` (including the `UITableViewCell` superclass outlets). What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was registering, in the test, the class for the `TableViewCell` and not the nib, but when I loaded the nib, I got other errors. It turns out that you need to register the nib of the custom cell, but declare it's bundle to be in the `Test target`.

Therefore, the register call looks like this:

```
vc.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: TableViewCell.classForCoder())), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

This makes all outlets work in the cell, and testing can ensue!

Comment: It does not seem to work. @BHendricks Is there any sequence that you follow to do it? It would be great if you provide more details.

Comment: In the test project? @Julio Bailon

Comment: Yes. I have tried every single combination without any luck